# WebComponent Layout is in reverse order

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Can anyone help me to understand why this layout is being rendered?

```js
customElements.define(
  "my-resume",
  class myresume extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
      h1.textContent="My Resume Name";
      this.appendChild(h1);
    }
  }
);

customElements.define(
  "job-experience",
  class jobexperience extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
      h1.textContent="Job Experience";
      this.appendChild(h1);
    }
  }
);

customElements.define(
  "company-name",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.textContent = this.getAttribute("name");
      this.appendChild(div);    
    }

  }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Resume Template</title>
    <script src="myresume.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myresume.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-resume>
      <job-experience>
        <company-name name="The Last Company Worked"></company-name>
      </job-experience>
    </my-resume>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: The layout is in reverse]

The element view:
[image: Element view]

I can understand why the entire layout is reverse that of the HTML mark up.  If for example I move the H1 elements up to the top of the parent container things are better. But I don't understand why each new custom element acts like a stack (each new element is pushed on the top) the last element added is always on rendered above other elements.

Custom Element creation logic determines the order of creation. It starts at each parent element and works its way down. But append child reverses the order because the browser will always render the last child appended first.

Comment: try using prepend(), as the children are going to be created/rendered before the constructor gets called as the parent hasnt been fully parsed/created

Comment: And don't access or create DOM in the ``constructor``, it will run for ``createElement`` But there won't be any DOM yet. Use the ``connectecCallback``. https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Patric Evans, your layout is rendering that way because you are using [appendChild] which inserts your node after the last child. If you use [prepend] your layout will render the way you expect.

As mentioned by Danny Engleman, don't do DOM manipulation in the constructor.

I believe this is more like what you are wanting..

```js
customElements.define(
  "my-resume",
  class myresume extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.textContent="My Resume Name";
        this.prepend(h1);
        // this.appendChild(h1);
    }
  }
);

customElements.define(
  "job-experience",
  class jobexperience extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
      h1.textContent="Job Experience";
      // this.appendChild(h1);
      this.prepend(h1);

    }
  }
);

customElements.define(
  "company-name",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.textContent = this.getAttribute("name");
      // this.appendChild(div);
      this.prepend(div);
    }

  }
);
```

```html
<my-resume>
    <job-experience>
        <company-name name="The Last Company Worked"></company-name>
    </job-experience>
</my-resume>
```